# how to print the value of variables in graphic mode of turbo c++?

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

The order of print something in turbo c++ in graphic mode is :

```
outtextxy(xmid,ymid,"...")
```

but I wanna print the value of a variable.what should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
char msg[128];
sprintf(msg, "variable=%d", variable);
outtextxy(xmin, ymid, msg);
```